# Finding out command line Data loader version

Tags: api

In my project,using command line data loader for past 7 years.I am not able to find out version of command line data loader in Production.

is there any way to know the version number?

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line#Basics) suggest that the API version would be in the folder path.
If there are any executable files you could also check the file properties details tab for the Product version (in Windows at least)